# Dialog Return Item value is not returned

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am using Oracle APEX 21.1. I've created a report with a form. The query of the report is...

```
SELECT DECODE(I.visit_type_id, 1, '<a href="' ||APEX_PAGE.GET_URL (p_page => 2, p_clear_cache=> '2', p_items =>'P2_ID,P2_VISIT_ID', p_values => I.EXAMINATION_FOLLOWUP_ID ||',' ||I.VISIT_ID) || '">فحص</a>', '<a href="' ||APEX_PAGE.GET_URL (p_page => 5, p_clear_cache=> '5', p_items => 'P5_ID,P5_PATIENT_ID,P5_VISIT_ID', p_values=> I.EXAMINATION_FOLLOWUP_ID ||',' ||P.ID ||',' ||I.VISIT_ID) || '">متابعة</a>') process_patient,
           I.VISIT_ID,
           I.PATIENT_ID,
           I.VISIT_DATE,
           I.VISIT_TYPE_ID,
           I.REFERRED_FROM_ID,
           I.EXAMINATION_FOLLOWUP_ID,
           P.NAME PATIENT_NAME,
           P.AGE,
           C.NAME CITY
    FROM
      (SELECT V.ID VISIT_ID,
              V.PATIENT_ID,
              V.VISIT_DATE,
              V.VISIT_TYPE_ID,
              V.REFERRED_FROM_ID,
              E.ID EXAMINATION_FOLLOWUP_ID
       FROM PATIENT_VISIT V
       LEFT JOIN EXAMINATION E ON E.VISIT_ID = V.ID
       WHERE VISIT_TYPE_ID = 1
       UNION ALL SELECT V.ID VISIT_ID,
                        V.PATIENT_ID,
                        V.VISIT_DATE,
                        V.VISIT_TYPE_ID,
                        NULL REFERRED_FROM_ID,
                             F.ID FOLLOW_UP_ID
       FROM PATIENT_VISIT V
       LEFT JOIN FOLLOW_UP F ON F.VISIT_ID = V.ID
       WHERE VISIT_TYPE_ID = 2 ) I
    JOIN PATIENT P ON P.ID = I.PATIENT_ID
    LEFT JOIN CITY C ON C.ID = P.CITY_ID;
```

As you can see, there are 2 modal pages that should open based on `visit_type_id` which is the parameter to the `DECODE` function. This is the part where the problem resides. In modal page 2, I created an item and a process to set the item's value to the REQUEST VALUE `:P2_REQUEST := :REQUEST`. In page 14(the report page), I've created an item `P14_REQUEST` and a `Dialog Closed` dynamic action with the `When` section's `Selection Type` set to `javaScript expression` and the expression = `window`. Then added a true action (Set Value) with `type` = `dialog return item`. The item is P2_REQUEST and the affected element is P14_REQUEST. The value of the request is returned successfully to P14_REQUEST. The problem is about the second page(5). When I do the same steps aforementioned, the value of the request is not returned at all. Is there a bug or something prevent working with multiple modal pages?
I have created a simulation on apex.oracle.com - a report(7) that calls 2 modal pages(9 and 10), when you update any value in any modal page and submits the page, the request value should be returned to P7_REQUEST. Unfortunately, that does not happen now using either pages.  Maybe I am missing something.

```
ws= ESLAM_WS
un= forhelp  
pwd= Forhelppwd$  
app= help  
pages= 7, 9 and 10
```

Comment: This is a whole lot of unreadable mess. You said "no need to read the whole query", but I gave up right after reading that sentence. From my point of view, if you want any kind of assistance, put some effort into making it formatted and easier to read and understand.  Also, don't write the whole message as a single sentence. True - someone else might try to help regardless of what I've just said. If so, good. Otherwise ...

Comment: I tried posting it formatted at first, but I faced an error preventing me from posting the question. Anyway, I think it's ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I forgot to set `Items to return` attribute of the `Close Dialog` process.